# What is equivalent to preg_replace & base64_decode in Java from PHP?

Tags: java

I have below code in PHP

**$file_data = base64_decode(preg_replace('/^data:application.*base64,(.*)/i', '$1',  $data]));**

When I am trying to convert it to JAVA

```
    String data = 'Whole string with data';
    data = data.replaceAll('/^data:application.*base64,(.*)/i', '$1');
```

It is saying invalid character

Comment: Literal strings must start and end with double quotes (") in Java, no simple quotes

Comment: Hi @Guillaume It may be basic in Java but good catch. Thanks